Bad value for type long" Error in Hibernate when Mapping ManyToMany relationship
I’m encountering an issue while working on a Spring Boot application that uses Hibernate for ORM.
Could not extract column [3] from JDBC ResultSet [Bad value for type long : Allows creating new projects] [n/a]"

**I have the following database tables:
**

Roles Table: Contains role IDs(long) and names(String).

Permissions Table: Contains permission IDs(long), descriptions(text), and permission(String).

Role_Permission Table: A many-to-many mapping table linking role Ids to permission Ids.


here is setup in Role entity
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "role_permission",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id")
    )
    private Set<Permission> permissions;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role")
    private Set<User> users;

and this is Permission entity
@Entity
@Table(name = "permissions")
public class Permission {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "permission", nullable = false)
    private String permission;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "description", nullable = true, columnDefinition = "text")
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "permissions")
    private Set<Role> roles;

relevant User entity code
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", nullable = false)
    private Role role;

User newUser = new User();
            newUser.setUsername(registrationDto.getUsername());
            newUser.setEmail(registrationDto.getEmail());
            newUser.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(registrationDto.getPassword()));
            newUser.setRole(roleRepository.findByName(registrationDto.getRole()));

            Role manager = newUser.getRole();

The problem I think is that there are no permissions loading instead there is PersistanceSet object and it has set = null
I have tried FetchType.EAGER loading but it didn't change anything. I dont understand why its fetching all users with the given role but not a single permission.
And yes my role_permission table is correctly populated :D
ps: sorry if this post is wrongly formatted, this is my first post here ever.

change  primitive long to wrapper Long for null safety then change your association in both classes Role and Permissions  (also Initialized collections to avoid null sets):
permission Entity :
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "permissions", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>(); 

Role Entity :
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

